# ATLAddressBarViewController.h not found in Atlas.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, layer, bridging-header

I am trying to run https://github.com/kwkhaw/quick-start-ios-swift this project. But facing this error while compiling the code.
[image: Following is the image description for the same.]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as yourself after I had upgraded to Xcode 7. Go to `Target -> Search Paths -> User Header Search Paths` and make sure you are not missing `Pods/** - recursive`. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Just to save someone else some time. If you are missing this path you should add `$(PODS_ROOT)` and set it to recursive. Add it to the *app* target and it will automatically figure out the correct path.

Comment: Can someone post the text from their Header Search Paths?